# How to maintain the status of each order item in magento2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

In magento-2.1, If an order has multiple items, it gives the only status of the order. In Flipkart, Myntra etc. it shows order status of each item of an order. I want to know Magento give this functionality or not?

Comment: Anybody tell me....

Comment: Have you found any solution ??

Comment: No @user4536 ..

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Magento2 doesn't have a status for orderitems as you would expect it.

They are however multiple quantity fields, that give you information

- qty_backordered
- qty_canceled
- qty_invoiced
- qty_ordered
- qty_refunded
- qty_shipped

(These are from EE, so you might have less in CE)